# Where can I buy designs for my t-shirt website?

Tags: copyright, apparel

I'm building a t-shirt website and I want to be all legal and stuff. I want to offer the customers interesting designs, like the ones from threadless.com or zazzle.com.

So the question would be... where and how do I buy designs that I can later sell on my website? I know there are interesting sites like designcrowd where you can get nice designs for your ideas, but what I really want is existing designs that I can sell on my website.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of places you can either hire designers or approach them for existing pieces. Hiring them would be more flexible on the legal side for you to use/reproduce the designs however.

For hiring, try freelance sites such as http://www.microlancer.com/, or even look into portfolio sites like http://www.behance.net/ or http://dribbble.com/ to approach someone with the design style you are after.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a search for [**t-shirt designs for sale**](https://www.google.com/search?q=t-shirt+designs+for+sale&oq=t-shirt+designs&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.4684j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) you get:

- [Mintees](http://www.mintees.com/tees/selected/artwork-for-sale)
- [T-Shirt artworks](http://www.tshirtartworks.com/)
- [Graphicriver](http://graphicriver.net/category/t-shirts)

Also, dont forget to check the copyright when you buy designs.  You may not be allowed but one print or only for a single use run (IE: 35 shirts at once).

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, you can buy custom designs, based on your needs from http://www.designcrowd.com .

For a fee, you can post a project requesting any type of design you require with a deadline, receive design submissions for various designers, which can also be revised. They even have a money back guarantee in case you're not satisfied with the submissions.

Accepting a design automatically transfers the copyright over to your name, and you receive editable files in either .psd or vector format, both, or in any form you should request them.